# Remote proxy with shared memory in C++

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, shared-memory

Suppose I have a daemon that is sharing it's internal state to various applications via shared memory.  Processes can send IPC messages to the daemon on a named pipe to perform various operations.  In this scenario, I would like to create a C++ wrapper class for clients that acts as a kind of "Remote Proxy" to hide some of the gory details (synchronization, message passing, etc) from clients and make it easier to isolate code for unit tests.

I have three questions:

- Generally, is this a good idea/approach?
- Do you have any tips or gotchas for synchronization in this setup, or is it enough to use a standard reader-writer mutex setup?
- Are there any frameworks that I should consider?

The target in question is an embedded linux system with a 2.18 kernel, therefore there are limitations on memory and compiler features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Herb Sutter had an article [Sharing Is the Root of All Contention](http://www.ddj.com/architect/214100002) that I broadly agree with; if you are using a shared memory architecture, you are exposing yourself to quite a bit of potential threading problems.

A client/server model can make things drastically simpler, where clients write to the named server pipe, and the server writes back on a unique client pipe (or use sockets). It would also make unit testing simpler (since you don't have to worry about testing shared memory), could avoid mutexing, etc.

Comment: Sure, I absolutely agree with this point of view.  I have the opinion that making the proxy class would be a good first step in this direction.  Once the access is hidden to the clients it seems it would be much easier to move to another sharing mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) library, though I can't comment on its suitability for embedded systems.